# JQuery compatibility style with css method

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to reproduce this compat-style:

```html
<div style="position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky;">
```

With JQuery `css()` function ?

```js
$('#element').css({'position': '<?>'});
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to change the prop('style')

Comment: Or better yet, make a class and add the class instead.

Comment: Create a class seems to be the best practice. Thank you for your help.